# Strange website loading redirect issue in IE9

Tags: performance, internet-explorer-9

I run and manage the website http://onedirection.net, and we've spent a lot of time recently trying to improve the loading speed of the site. There's a lot of content on the site which requires load time, but everything else is going smoothly.

In Chrome, we're very happy with the load speed, but things don't seem as good in IE9. In fact when we load the homepage up, it seems to pause for a while, but worse still when I click and hold the Back button, I can see about 6-7 redirects from the initial page load!

What is causing this? There are no redirects on the site, but it looks like the social media links and a couple of adverts are causing strange problems.

I've never seen this before, so I'm a bit stumped!

Also, the chat bar at the bottom of the site doesn't load properly on the homepage, but does on other pages.

Can anyone shed any light into what is causing these issues, and better still how to solve it?

Thanks,

Chris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest performance in Chrome isn't that great - from my home connection the page takes 11 seconds to load in Chrome.

Here's a waterfall for the home page in IE9 from a server in Dublin - http://www.webpagetest.org/result/120901_NC_f64ed067693fda62238e67cce432f964/1/details/

The waterfall is pretty horrible to be honest - too many requests, too many domains, no prioritisation of content, javascript in the head loading in a blocking manner

I'd need to look in more depth but essentially due to the number of third party components you've lost control of your page load.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your response. We agree there are a lot external requests, and we're looking for ways to reduce these. We think some of the ads are playing silly buggers so might look into alternate suppliers, and may also remove some of the social media plugins. A lot of the javascript has been moved down to the bottom of the site already but it looks like we'll have to move most or all of it down there too. Do you have any idea what may be causing the strange IE redirect issue?

Comment: We've made some changes Andy and we can see a definite speed increase, though the ads are still causing issues. Can you see if theres an improvement on your end?